# CreateContainerError when using static IP for another ingress controller. Can you use a single IP for more than one load balancer or ingress in AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, static-ip-address

I created a deployment in AKS/Kubernetes that was assigned an ingress controller to another application. In the meanwhile I setup another deployment using that static IP. Everything worked fine.

When I closed the app and shut down the ingress controller, in preparation for the new deployment, I got this `CreateContainerError` error.

```js
State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CreateContainerError
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sun, 25 Sep 2022 09:53:35 -0400
      Finished:     Sat, 15 Oct 2022 19:54:07 -0400
```

I have 2 questions.

1. In AKS can you use a single static IP per multiple services? Or should I not really do that.

The [stack here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018588/kubernetes-gke-multiple-ingresses-single-global-ip) seems to touch on the subject with GKE.

2. The [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls?tabs=azure-cli#use-a-static-public-ip-address) seems to say you can but a more definitive answer would be helpful. I am unsure if an IP can service more than ingress in a cluster.

> A common configuration requirement is to provide the NGINX ingress controller an existing static public IP address. The static public IP address remains if the ingress controller is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> In AKS can you use a single static IP per multiple services? Or should
> I not really do that.

Yes, you can do it with an any ingress controller.

You have to use the same like **GKE** stack only

**ingress** is managed by the **ingress controller**, so you have to create ingress with different configurations, and the ingress controller will configure it as per the rules and do the request routing for you.

If you go below in that same document of F

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - hello-world-ingress.MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: hello-world-ingress.MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello-world-one(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld-one
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /hello-world-two(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld-two
            port:
              number: 80
```

**ingressClassName** is which connect the ingress and ingress controller.

> When I closed the app and shut down the ingress controller, in
> preparation for the new deployment

you don't have to close the ingress controller it will be there one running, and multiple ingress rules will be running.

Comment: Do you mean, and I read, that you can use the same IP but the ingressClassName has to be different?

Comment: updated the answer with more details

Comment: you still don't reference the class name aspect. you can do this but with the class name reference.

Comment: I see the confusion. it's this part that was tripping me up. The documentation here seems to say you can but a more definitive answer would be helpful. I am unsure if an IP can service more than ingress in a cluster.

Comment: So what I am asking is can you use a single ip with more than 1 ingress. You can. It's with the classname. There is a specific kubernetes instruction for that.

Comment: yes you can use the ingress multiple with the single IP, you can use the class based on ingress controller you are using and single IP will work for ingress. But you can not use the single IP for multiple ingress controller.

Comment: ingress controller have one IP and it will managed the ingress file that i have above shared so you can create other rules or files as per need. So ingress controller or nginx controller will have the one IP with the service and it will manged the ingress object that we are creating abvoe with the YAML file.